# warning: cast from 'char *' to 'float *' increases required alignment from 1 to 4 [-Wcast-align]

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way for me to use the c++11 keyword [alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) to decorate the function `get()`. Under certain condition I know that the buffer returned by `get()` will contain properly aligned floating point buffer.

Code:

```
$ cat c.cxx
extern char* get();

void foo()
{
  float *f = (float*)get();
}
```

leads to

```
$ clang++-8 -Wcast-align -c c.cxx
c.cxx:5:14: warning: cast from 'char *' to 'float *' increases required alignment from 1 to 4 [-Wcast-align]
  float *f = (float*)get();
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

For reference the function `char* get()`, simply return `&v[0]` of a `std::vector<char>` which depending of the internal type may contains a byte buffer or a float buffer (variant).

Comment: Something tells me the warning can be removed by casting to `void *` first.

Comment: Why not use static_cast to a float *? Does that remove the warning?

Comment: How does `get()` know how many char's it should put in its buffer?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend against using C-style casts and favoring `reinterpret_cast` instead. This also has the nice property of getting rid of the warning.

However, to answer your question proper:

Since C++20 you can use [`std::assume_aligned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/assume_aligned) like so:

```
extern char* get();

void foo()
{
  float *f = (float*)std::assume_aligned<alignof(float)>(get());
}
```

Pre C++20, you can also use non-portable compiler intrinsics:

```
extern char* get();

void foo()
{
  float *f = (float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(get(), alignof(float));
}
```

Comment: and probably `std::alignment_of_v<float>` instead of `4`.

Comment: still I shame I cannot decorate the actual `get` function instead.

Comment: The question asks for C++11 though. No down vote from me though, since it is still handy to know other versions of C++.

Comment: If the pointer returned by `get()` isn't aligned, `std::assume_aligned` won't help if I understand the wiki correctly. "_The behavior is undefined if ptr does not point to an object of type T (ignoring cv-qualification at every level),_"

Comment: @Chipster Hence the "pre-C++20" comment below.

Comment: @TedLyngmo This assumption is explicitly acknowledged by OP. `Under certain condition I know that the buffer returned by get() will contain properly aligned floating point buffer.`

Comment: Yes, ok, but what does `std::assume_aligned` really help with if you tell it to assume `float` alignment for something that has `float` alignment? What optimization could possibly be done with that information? It seems to only be useful when supplying an alignment that is bigger than what the original type requires. Not sure ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo It has float alignment, but the compiler *doesn't know that*. It's essentially a static analysis helper.

Comment: *"Since C++20"* sounds like we are in >= 2020 :)

Comment: @milleniumbug Shouldn't the compiler make the same assumption when you `reinterpret_cast<float*>`? It would be strange if it didn't since accessing the pointed to memory via the `float*` would also be UB if it wasn't aligned.

Comment: ... and shouldn't it be: `float *f = std::assume_aligned<alignof(float)>(reinterpret_cast<float*>(get()));`

Answer (score 1):

Under what kind of conditions? If it always returns a float buffer, make it so (`float* get()`), if sometimes it does not, a static decorator will not help.

If you know that the returned pointer points to a float, `reinterpret_cast` can be used. If it does not, but you still want a float, [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) or [bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) (C++20) can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Warnings are just messages from the compiler to warn the programmer (you) that something is suspect. In the general case, converting from a `char *` to a `float *` can cause alignment problems hence the warning.

If you know that in your use case, no alignment problem will ever occur and that strict aliasing is not a problem either, then you can safely ignore the warning. Be sure to leave a comment in the code for future maintainers not to worry about that warning at that place.

After reading again last line of your question, I would not rely on using the data buffer of a `vector<char>` for that usage. At least you should use a `vector<float>`: by definition it can contain floats, and it is always safe to access any type (here an array or floats) as a char array.

Comment: Turns out this is actually the best answer, not ideal since I'd like to have a keyword for the actual function. But changing the function signature to return `void*` will make sure user will actually read the documentation.

Comment: Trouble is I see no evidence in the question that the warning is in any way wrong. Why is everybody recommending to inhibit it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: OP has said in question: *Under certain condition I know that the buffer returned by get() will contain properly aligned floating point buffer*. As would do a kind compiler, I warn OP that he is responsible for alignment and strict aliasing respect, and I trust him to know what he does. **I** know, that if `get` returns a `malloc`-ed buffer, or a pointer to a float or an array of float, then it will be fine.

Comment: @SergeBallesta They also said it comes from a `std::vector<char>`. Will that be okay?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Close to an angels sex debate :-). It is certainly UB, but I had read some vector implementations and all of them use an allocated buffer for their data. So deep inside the internals of the standard library, the vector data buffer has no declared type and is properly aligned for any type. But I must admit I would not use that in production code!

Comment: @SergeBallesta Okay no that makes sense actually

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Anyway, I have edited my post to better reflect the question you raised.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for the edit. I was under the impression that C++ standard requires allocation functions (malloc() and operator new()) to allocate memory suitably aligned for any standard type (eg. `float` or `double`). Since internally std::vector data are allocated, I do not understand you last (edited) comment.

Comment: @malat: The problem is that as noticed by  LightnessRacesinOrbit, you can always store a float representation in the data member of a `vector<char>`, but using type punning to use it as a float is formally UB, even if most if not all implementations will allow it. The allocator is supposed to return a char array when ask to, but I do not think that it guarantees that the char array has no declared type.